# Windows batch operation for adding pdf page dimensions to filename?

Tags: windows, pdf, batch-file, batch-rename

I need to include page size information of many single-paged pdf's into their filenames. E.g. "150x250mm.pdf". I found no renamer apps able to do it. I suspect this could be done using a batch file and pdfinfo.exe (from xpdf suite), but I have no idea how to make use of it.. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: It looks like pdfinfo outputs the page size metadata in pts. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Not as a final result.. But if pts directly convertable to mm, maybe there's just an operation to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can convert from postscript points to MM. In this case, the script is in the top level folder containing the PDF's to be renamed. It does go into subfolders. If you don't want or need that, remove the /s from the dir command on the 5th line. Change the paths as needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pdfi=U:\Scripts\Utilities\xpdf\pdfinfo.exe"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s *.pdf') do (
  for /f "tokens=3,5 delims= " %%b in (
    '%pdfi% -meta "%%a"^|find /i "Page size:"') do (
      set pts=%%b %%c
        for %%d in (!pts!) do (
          call :Eval %%d*.352777778 mm
          set "mm1=!mm1!x!mm!"
        )
        ren "%%~dpfnxa" "!mm1:~1!.pdf"
        set mm1=
  )
)
exit /b

:Eval <in> <out>
setlocal
if exist eval.vbs del eval.vbs
>eval.vbs echo wsh.echo formatnumber(eval("%1"),0)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
  'cscript //nologo eval.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~2=%%a
del eval.vbs
```

Comment: Wow, this does calculate sizes in mm for sure (I saw them being output in array), but didn't rename the files in the end.. Will come back to that shortly to check what's really wrong.

Comment: remove the `echo` from in front of the ren command. I only added it for testing.

Comment: Almost here! One last problem: the script spills the whole array into the filename. Do you know how to fix it? See http://i.imgur.com/mS0dj9C.png

Comment: Yes, I forgot to zero out the mm1 variable. Try the code now.